# Set up scrapy cluster on AWS

Tags: python, scrapy, amazon-ecs

I am looking to set up scrapy-cluster on an Amazon cluster (EC2 container services), however I am unfamiliar with both the package and with distributed computing. I already have a working version of the scrapy working, but it's time to scale. The scrapy-cluster documentation talks about setting up vagrant, however I am unsure how I could spin up say 10 instances with the distributed scraping happening across all of them. Could someone please outline the steps to do this or point me in the right direction.

Comment: I believe you'll need to ask for setup help on https://gitter.im/istresearch/scrapy-cluster